# My neofetch looks extremely weird

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux

I'm new to Linux and have been distro hopping on VirtualBox these days. Today, I went on Kali Linux and tried to make it look like Windows because why not? I wanted to change neofetch from the Kali logo to the Windows logo, so I did `cd .config/neofetch/` when I was on ~ directory, then I did `vim config.conf` and edited the document. It ended up looking like this:

[image: Logo being consumed by the text]

Also, here's the file I edited:

```
print_info () {
    info title
    info underline

    info "Host" model
    info "OS" distro
    info "Kernel" kernel
    info "Uptime" uptime
    info "Packages" packages
    info "Shell" shell
    info "Resolution" resolution
    info "Terminal" term
    info "CPU" cpu
    info "GPU" gpu
    info "Memory" memory

    info cols
}

    distro_shorthand="off"
    package_managers="off"
    separator="-->"
    ascii_distro="windows"
    ascii_colors=(1 2 3 4)
```

Does anyone know why it's doing this?
P.S. I have tried removing and installing the neofetch pagage again and also have tried `sudo apt install neofetch`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like things aren't lining up because your terminal font is not a monospace font.

Comment: That makes sense as I switched my font before executing neofetch. Thanks.